# How to block non-numbers?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, call-sms-filter

Recently I've been getting promotional SMS messages, and I'd like to block them. Problem is, they don't seem to be coming from an actual phone number, instead the sender shown is the name of the company behind the messages.

[image]

There's no option to block the number when viewing the messages. The built-in Block and Filter app doesn't allow adding non-numeric entries to the block list. Ditto for Truecaller (which I normally use for blocking spam calls and messages). Since the sender is not a valid phone number, I cannot call it either, to block it from the call log.

Are there any other options for blocking the messages?

Comment: Do you "Block calls with no caller ID"?

Comment: @RowlandShaw That's in the Block and Filter app? I'm using Truecaller right now, but I'll switch to that and see what happens. But does that option also apply to SMS messages? Or only calls?

Comment: It certainly did on Windows 8.x; Can't say I've noticed any since 10 either...

Comment: @RowlandShaw Unfortunately that didn't work, I'm still getting SMS spam from non-numbers.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, though. As I said, the built-in Block and Filter app doesn't allow adding non-numeric entries directly. However, if I add the sender to my contact list, then I can add them to the block list using the "+" sign in the text field. I've done that now, time will tell if this works.

Comment: Did adding of the number to contact list work?